# How to prove $ 1 \mathrel | a $ for all $ a $.

Tags: divisibility

> Prove $ 1 \mathrel | a $ for all $ a $.

So far I have $ a = 1 \times a $.
I'm pretty sure that is my answer but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: What is your definition of $x$ divides $y$?

Answer (score -1):

An integer x divides an integer y if you can write $y = xk$ with k an integer. You can write any integer y as $y  = y1$ and therefore 1 divides all integers.